# Как воспроизвести звук в фоне?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.x, python-2.7

То есть я запускаю сценарий он проигрывает музыку(никаких окон не должно появляться(кроме самой консоли)) в фоне и сценарий выполняться, но музыка еще играет т.е музыка играет во время выполнения сценария, как это можно реализовать? В windows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44472225/5741205

Comment: Чтобы музыка были при выполнении сценария, нужно их разделить, например код с музыкой будет выполняться в побочном потоке (или в процессе), а сценарий -- в главном

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import winsound
winsound.PlaySound("filename", winsound.SND_ASYNC | winsound.SND_ALIAS )
```

Comment: А `winsound.PlaySound` выполняется асинхронно? Код после `winsound.PlaySound` сразу выполняется или после окончания мелодии, предположу что `winsound.SND_ASYNC` как раз и говорит о асинхронном выполнении